# Maximum number of feature dimensions

Tags: machine-learning

I have a classification problem and my current feature vector does not seem to hold enough information.
My training set has 10k entries and I am using a SVM as classifier (scikit-learn).

What is the maximum reasonable feature vector size (how many dimension)?
(Training and evaluation using Labtop CPU)

100? 1k? 10k? 100k? 1M?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is not how many features should it be for a certain number of cases (i.e. entries) but rather the opposite:

> It’s not who has the best algorithm that wins. It’s who has the most data. (Banko and Brill, 2001)

Banko and Brill in 2001 made a comparison among 4 different algorithms, they kept increasing the **Training Set Size** to millions and came up with the above-quoted conclusion.

Moreover, Prof. Andrew Ng clearly covered this topic, and I’m quoting here:

> If a learning algorithm is suffering from high variance, **getting more training data is likely to help.**
>
> If a learning algorithm is suffering from high bias, getting more training data will not (**by itself**) help much

---

So as a rule of thumb, your data cases must be greater than the number of features in your dataset taking into account that all features should be informative as much as possible (*i.e. the features are not highly collinear (i.e. redundant)*).

I read once in more than one place and somewhere in Scikit-Learn Documentation, that the number of inputs (i.e. samples) must be at least the square size of the number of features (i.e. `n_samples > n_features ** 2` ).

---

Nevertheless, for `SVM` in particular, the number of features `n` v.s number of entries `m` is an important factor to specify the type of kernel to use initially, as a second rule of thumb for `SVM` in particular (also according to Prof. Andrew Ng):

1. If thr number of features is **much greater** than number of entries (i.e. `n` is up to **10K** and `m` is up to **1K**) --> use `SVM` *without a kernel* (i.e. "*linear kernel*") or use *Logistic Regression*.
2. If the number of features is **small** and if the number of entries is **intermediate** (i.e. `n` is up to **1K** and `m` is up to **10K**)  --> use `SVM` with *Gaussian kernel*.
3. If the number of feature is **small** and if the number of entries is much **larger**  (i.e. `n` is up to **1K** and `m` > **50K**) --> Create/add more features, then use `SVM` *without a kernel* or use *Logistic Regression*.